# how to change bootstrap input text box style to line?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working in laravel with bootstarp css. now I need change input text box style to line....
this is My bootstrap input text box

```
<div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('name') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                <label for="name" class="control-label">Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="name" value="{{ old('name') ?: '' }}">
                @if ($errors->has('name'))
                    <span class="help-block">{{ $errors->first('name') }}</span>
                @endif
            </div>
```

I wrote css file as follow

```
#input {
    background: transparent;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
}
```

line is come but bootstrap input box style is still there. how can remove bootstrap style and make My input box as line

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this:

```css
html {
  /* for demo purposes only */
  margin: 2em;
}

input[type="text"],
select.form-control {
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  border-radius: 0;
}

input[type="text"]:focus,
select.form-control:focus {
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="form-group">
  <label for="name" class="control-label">Name</label>
  <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="name" value="test">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label for="dropdown-test" class="control-label">Dropdown test</label>

  <select class="form-control" name="dropdown-test">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
  <option>5</option>
</select>
</div>
```

The `:focus` rule is so that only the underline changes colour when the input control is focused, otherwise you'll still see the default blow 'glow'.

Comment: what about your css file? it should My external css or is it bootstrap file

Comment: The `<link>` referenced is the standard Bootstrap CSS (you won't need this if you've already included it in your code). To add the `input` styles, either include it in an external `.css` file, or add it to a `<style type="text/css"></style>` block in the `<head>` of your document.

Comment: well it is working I have another problem that is how can change <option> value Attribute field like line?

Comment: see code above - edited to support `<select>` dropdown controls.

Comment: Nice, used with Bootstrap-5!!

Answer (score 2):

## input is targeting an id named input(which I don't see in your code).

You need to target input itself by removing the #, or... change #input to #name since that is the actual id.

Answer (score 2):

Change `#input` in css to `#name`.In your html the id for input is gives as `name`

```css
#name {
    background: transparent;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
    outline:none;
    box-shadow:none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="form-group ">
                <label for="name" class="control-label">Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="name" value="">
            
            </div>
```

Comment: did it but still here is some shadow of bootstrap input style

Comment: may I need more style decorations in My css file?

Comment: @flex Updated snippet plz check